# Is it possible to create your own content for IntelliJ's Edu plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea

I recently downloaded the Kotlin Koans, and notice that they are written/run within a JetBrains plugin which appears to be called Edu.

I was wondering if anybody knows if it is possible to create your own content for this plugin?

I think it would be useful in orientating new employees with our coding practices, create little courses for new frameworks we use, but most of all I thought it would be quite useful in the technical section of interviews, actually getting our interviewees writing code.

Apologies if this is an off topic question, or the answer is ask JetBrains.  Just thought I would ask the community first.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the [Kotlin-Koans-for-Edu](https://github.com/medvector/Kotlin-Koans-for-Edu) repository on GitHub. The contents of a course seem to be defined by the [course.json](https://github.com/medvector/Kotlin-Koans-for-Edu/blob/master/course.json) file.

It appears that courses can be installed as an IntelliJ IDEA plugin: see the [Educational plugin for Kotlin](https://github.com/medvector/edu-for-kotlin) GitHub repository for more information.

Good luck diving into this, it would be very nice if you could build upon the existing infrastructure!

Comment: I didn't think about that.  I will drop JetBrains a line as well.  Yeah thats exactly what I was thinking.  ITs not exactly Xcode playgrounds, but it would be good.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: Could you update your question (or add an answer of your own) if you find out more details on how to get this to work, like for example from the people at JetBrains? That would be great for anyone that wants to do something similar.

Comment: If I find anything out, I will update this question.

Comment: Sorry for the late update; JetBrains gave me this link: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8233?pr=idea&showAllUpdates=true So once I get some time I am going to sit down and have a look.